# What is the purpose of finding the mean of each column and row of the images’ pixels in image processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

My question is regarding image processing techniques in MATLAB. I am designing a proof of concept which will discriminate the digit "4" from a large set of digit images.

I have used many image processing techniques such as edge detection. I am also using one technique where I get the mean pixel value of each column and row of the images. However, I am unsure what this feature extraction method does exactly. Can someone clarify why this is a type of feature extraction? And does this method have a particular name?

Comment: anything you compute in the image is a feature.... Its just some of them are more useful than others. E.g. you can see that edge detection sounds like a better feature than mean value of the image. But both are features

Comment: Thank you, but what does this feature do exactly?

Comment: I don't understand why this "feature" would be any more useful than just sticking in all pixels as features. The feature "vale at (i,j)" is meaningless, and so is "sum of values at row i". Meaningless features sometimes allow a classifier to give good results, but you'll never understand the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call these kind of features as statistical features. They can be useful in some problems, but not sure about the digits. In my opinion, you should also use variance as a feature. You can check this paper with statistical features:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a0d/c802a6e6f7b193e2b90cb84ca119ebb1e705.pdf

Image moments are also useful, you can explore the use of them: 
http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS7960-S2010/handouts/CS7960-AdvImProc-MomentInvariants.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in a way it is a type of feature extraction. The mean of each row is the sum of the pixel values over the number of pixels. The sum of the pixels could be interpreted as a projection of the image onto the y axis. Same goes for the columns but as a projection on the x axis.

Whether that type of feature extraction helps you depends on your problem.